# Replace string with spaces in entire directory

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, find

I want to replace 'Aux Power [A]' in all files to 'aux_power'.
Only the files with 'Aux Power [A]' can be modified, the rest need to remain untouched.
I have tried

```
grep -lR "Aux Power [A]" /mnt/d/power/jan/output | xargs sed -i "s/'Aux Power [A]'/'aux_power_w'/g"
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Please advice.

Comment: Just to clarify: You wish to change file contents, do you?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is twofold:

1. The `grep` command, by default, expects a regular expression pattern, not a string, and your string contains characters special to regular expressions (`[` and `]`).  You have the same issue in your `sed` substitution.
2. Filenames outputted by `grep -l` *may* be mangled. If a file contains an unprintable character (such as newline), `grep` will simply drop that from the outputted name.  This means that `sed` won't be invoked on that file.

---

This is assuming you'd like to replace the string within the file content, not in filenames:

To find all files beneath the directory `/mnt/d/power/jan/output` that contains the exact string `Aux Power [A]`, you would use

```
find /mnt/d/power/jan/output -type f \
    -exec grep -Fq 'Aux Power [A]' {} ';' -print
```

To change the string to `aux_power` you would extend that command like so:

```
find /mnt/d/power/jan/output -type f \
    -exec grep -Fq 'Aux Power [A]' {} ';' \
    -exec sed -i 's/Aux Power \[A\]/aux_power/g' {} ';'
```

This is assuming GNU `sed`.

The `grep -Fq` will not produce any output but will return a zero exit status for any file that contains the specified string (not regular expression since `-F` is used).

The `sed` command does in-place editing (the GNU way), changing all occurrences of the string (here specified as a regular expression, which is why the brackets are escaped).

If you'd like to get the names of the modified files listed in the terminal, then leave the `-print` in from the first `find` command, after the `-exec grep ... {} ';'`.

---

Since the `sed` expression that we're using here won't change the contents of a file that does not contain the particular string you want to change, you may shorten the command down to

```
find /mnt/d/power/jan/output -type f \
    -exec sed -i 's/Aux Power \[A\]/aux_power/g' {} ';'
```

This applies the substitution to *all* files under the `/mnt/d/power/jan/output` directory.  Any file that does not contain the string will remain unchanged (but its timestamp would still be updated).

Comment: You worry about file name mangling but fail to get the replacement right. Matthew 7:3.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Please explain and I will get it right.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille If you referring to the string `aux_power_w`, then all I can say is that the question asks to replace with `aux_power` while his attempt is to replace with `aux_power_w`. The attempt don't match the question, and it's uncertain which one is actually meant. If I have another error in my code, I'd be more than willing to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the square brackets for grep.  "[A]" is the same as "A".
Try

```
grep -lR "Aux Power \[A\]" /mnt/d/power/jan/output | xargs sed -i "s/Aux Power \[A\]/aux_power_w/g"
```